# How to combine these multiple queries in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query, where the final result I want is the $rate

```
// get latest effective date
    $effectiveDate = CpfEffectiveDate::where('effective_from', '<=', $currentDate)
            ->orderBy("effective_from", 'DESC')
            ->first();

// get scheme related to the effective date and citizenship type
    $scheme = CpfScheme::where("cpf_citizenship_id", $request->cpf_citizenship_id)
        ->where('cpf_effective_date_id', $effectiveDate->id)
        ->first();

// get rate based on scheme and other data
    $rate = CpfRate::where("cpf_scheme_id", $scheme->id)
            ->where("minimum_wage", '<', ceil($totalWage)) // query does not accept floats. should be acceptable as wage tiers should be integers
            ->where("minimum_age", '<', $request->employee_age)
            ->orderBy('minimum_wage', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('minimum_age', 'DESC')
            ->first();
```

How can I combine all 3 queries into a single one?

First I get the correct effective date from the first table, after which I use it to find the correct scheme (together with a citizenship_id) which I use to find the correct rate.

Here are the following models:

**CpfRate**

```
  class CpfRate extends Model
  {
    protected $table = "cpf_rates";

    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    protected $hidden = ["created_at", "updated_at"];

    public function scheme()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CpfScheme::class, "cpf_scheme_id");
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        "minimum_age",
        "minimum_wage",
        "employer_percentage",
        "employee_percentage",
        "employee_offset_amount", // used for special cases, such as -500 for percentage = 0.15 * (TW - 500)
        "ordinary_wage_cap", // ordinary wage cap
    ];
  }
```

**CpfScheme**

```
class CpfScheme extends Model
{
    protected $table = "cpf_schemes";

    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    protected $hidden = ["created_at", "updated_at"];

    public function citizenship()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CpfCitizenship::class, "cpf_citizenship_id");
    }

    public function effectiveDate()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CpfEffectiveDate::class, "cpf_effective_date_id");
    }
}
```

**CpfEffectiveDate**

```
class CpfEffectiveDate extends Model
{
    protected $table = "cpf_effective_dates";

    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    protected $hidden = ["created_at", "updated_at"];

    // mutated to dates
    protected $dates = ['effective_from'];

    public function schemes() {
        return $this->hasMany(CpfScheme::class, "cpf_effective_date_id");
    }
}
```

**CpfCitizenship**

```
class CpfCitizenship extends Model
{
    protected $table = "cpf_citizenships";

    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    protected $hidden = ["created_at", "updated_at"];

    // fields
    protected $fillable = ['description'];

    public function schemes() {
        return $this->hasMany(CpfScheme::class, "cpf_citizenship_id");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rate = CpfRate::select('cpf_rates.*')
    ->where('cpf_scheme_id', '=', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->select('id')
                ->from('cpf_schemes')
                ->where("cpf_citizenship_id", $request->cpf_citizenship_id)
                ->where('cpf_effective_date_id', '=', function($query, $currentDate) {
                    $query->select('id')
                            ->from('cpf_effective_dates')
                            ->where('effective_from', '<=', $currentDate)
                            ->orderBy("effective_from", 'DESC')
                            ->limit(1);
                })
                ->first();
    })
    ->where("minimum_wage", '<', ceil($totalWage)) // query does not accept floats. should be acceptable as wage tiers should be integers
    ->where("minimum_age", '<', $request->employee_age)
    ->orderBy('minimum_wage', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('minimum_age', 'DESC')
    ->first();
```

> I did not tested but what only here can be problem is $currentdate, so if it is problem just use Carbon class to get current date directly in query.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll test it out tomorrow...

Comment: It works. However I did not pass in $currentDate that way. Instead i put it under use() for the both nested function.

Also, I did not test your version out but I used different names for the function arguments, $query1 and $query2.

Thank you

Comment: I am happy that I helped you , if you are laravel and php developer we can connect on linkedin or twitter. for future helping connection.